# UpdateItem in DynamoDB error ValidationException: Invalid attribute value type

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table called `JuridicalPerson` in my DynamoDB

```
var params = {
  AttributeDefinitions: [{
    AttributeName: 'code',
    AttributeType: 'S'
  }],
  KeySchema: [{
    AttributeName: 'code',
    KeyType: 'HASH'
  }],
  ProvisionedThroughput: {
    ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
    WriteCapacityUnits: 5
  },
  TableName: 'JuridicalPerson'
}
```

I can save items there, but I can't update those items.

**Sample of item's in my JuridicalPerson table**

```
{
   "code": {
     "S": "jp_rJaHvVrzf"
   },
   "status": {
     "S": "pending"
   }
}
```

**Update Expression**

```
function updateDynamoDB (payload) {
  const adhesionUpdate = Object.assign({}, payload)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      TableName: 'JuridicalPerson',
      Key: {
        'code': {
          'S': adhesionUpdate.code
        }
      },
      UpdateExpression: 'SET #status = :val1',
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#status': 'status'
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':val1': { 'S': adhesionUpdate.status }
      },
      ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
    }

    return dynamoAdapter.getState().update(params, (err, items) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      return resolve(items)
    })
  })
}
```

If I put a `console.log` before the Update just to see the `params`, we have

```
params:  { TableName: 'JuridicalPerson',
  Key: { code: { S: 'jp_rJaHvVrzf' } },
  UpdateExpression: 'set #status = :val1',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#status': 'status' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':val1': { S: 'active' } },
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW' }
```

But I got the following error

```
err:  { ValidationException: Invalid attribute value type
  message: 'Invalid attribute value type',
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: 2017-12-18T12:40:39.488Z,
  requestId: 'bc23aab1-d9a5-426f-a1af-3ff558e7e0fa',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 41.054909592801195 }
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious error unless `status` is defined as a key in any secondary index, and if so of any other data type than string?

Comment: I know that the DynamoDB and the Document Client API documentation has sometimes been a bit ambigious in that sometimes values should *not* be described in the `{S: 'some value'}` form, but simply as `'some value'`. The documentation does however clearly state that `ExpressionAttributeValues` should be in the more verbose form, but if I were you I'd give it a try without the `{S: ...}`. Personally I have only been using the DocumentClient API since its release, mostly to get rid of the incredibly verbose syntax with all these `S:` and `N:`...

Comment: One small thing. Shouldn't your condition at the end have an 'else' (as in return an error else the results). Also, im not a javascript programmer, but there are a lot of return statements in there and its hard to see the flow of the code. Are you sure which code is being executed? Other than that I couldn't spot any problems at all in the actual DynamoDB parts.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same ambiguous error message when using the DynamoDb Client rather than the DynamoDb Resource.

The DDB Client accepts definitions of values in short form `key: value` rather than explicit type form accepted by the DDB resource `key: {'S': value}`.

In your example try using:

```
const params = {
  TableName: 'JuridicalPerson',
  Key: {
    'code': adhesionUpdate.code
  },
  UpdateExpression: 'SET #status = :val1',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#status': 'status'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':val1': adhesionUpdate.status
  },
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
}
```